# What does get to appended to the functions list (what's inside the func(x))

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, closures

This piece of code prints [16,16,16,16,16].

```
functions = []
for i in range(5):
    def func(x):
        return x + i
    functions.append(func)
for f in functions:
    print(f(12))
```

In the first for loop, when `i` takes the value 3, what's inside the func that gets append to the list? `func(x):x+3` or `func(x):x+i` or `func(x): x+i where i=3` ?

I assume the answer is `func(x):x+i`, where `i` doesn't take any actual value when appending to the list. Can someone explains to me using frame, closure, and scope concept? When `i = 3` is in the parent frame, why doesn't func(x) be appended as `x+3`?

Comment: why doesn't append the actual value since the value is in the parent frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use default arguments:

```
functions = []
for i in range(5):
    def func(x, a = i):
        return x + a
    functions.append(func)
for f in functions:
    print(f(12))
```

This works because the default value is evaluated when the function is created. Otherwise all functions will point to the last value of `i`.

Feel free to look at [Late Binding Closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) for more information on this.

> Python’s closures are late binding. This means that the values of variables used in closures are looked up at the time the inner function is called.

> Here, whenever any of the returned functions are called, the value of i is looked up in the surrounding scope at call time. By then, the loop has completed and i is left with its final value of 4.

The example in the guide uses `range(5)` so the quote directly applies to your function.

Comment: No, in this case it is evaluated when the function is executed and hence they all get the same `i` of `4`.

Comment: @pavel what do you mean? Go run my code. What you said is not true.

Comment: Oh no, sorry, I didn't see that you actually provided i as an argument. No, your code is good.

Comment: Simplifying a little, It is like a list of 5 same variables `[x,x,x,x,x]`. so if you change the value of x, all the elements will be changed.( as he is using same name of the function each time).

Comment: wow thanks! but im now even more confused with your magic example. can you please explain using the frame and closure? (im learning the concept, this is where the code is shown as an example to explain the concept)

Comment: @jazzfaz I added a link with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: In terms of closure, when the `func(x)` is added to the list, it is a closure which is storing a function here. And with each iteration you are updating the local value of that closure. So when you call function, the local variable `i` has already been updated to its latest value.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is higher order function.

```py
functions = []

for i in range(5):
    def func_maker(i):
        def _func(x):
            return x + i
        return _func

    functions.append(func_maker(i))

for f in functions:
    print(f(12))
```